# Given the spin and direction of propogation can we find polarization?

Tags: photons, nuclear-physics, polarization

A photon released by a $\sigma_+$ transition (with quantization axis in the $z$-direction) traveling along the $x$-axis is said to have a polarization in the $y$-direction. The only things we know about this photon are it's angular momentum $m_z=1$ and it's direction direction of propagation. From this how is it therefore possible to deduce that the photon has a polarization in the $y$-direction?

Is their a general method to determine the polarization of a photon with known angular momentum along a quantization direction angle $\theta$ to it's direction of propagation?

(A quantum mechanical rather then semi-classical explanation is desired.)

Comment: @flippiefanus That would be fine as an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The photon eigenstates of spin angular momentum (SAM) are the left- and right-circular polarization states. So if this state is in an SAM eigenstate with $m_z=1$, then it would not have polarization in the y-direction. The latter would be a linear polarization state, which does not have a definite SAM.